# Spacy - ValueError: Can't read file: models\model0\accuracy.json

Tags: python, command-line, spacy

I am  trying to train a spacy model on the command-line with the following code:

```
python -m spacy train en models TRAINDATA.json DEVDATA.json
```

This error occured: `ValueError: Can't read file: models\model0\accuracy.json`

I already created an empty directory but unfortunatly I got the same error.

Traceback:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m spacy train en models  C:\Windows\System32\TRAINDATAconverted.json C:\Windows\System32\TRAINDATAconverted.json
⚠ Output directory is not empty
This can lead to unintended side effects when saving the model. Please use an
empty directory or a different path instead. If the specified output path
doesn't exist, the directory will be created for you.
Training pipeline: ['tagger', 'parser', 'ner']
Starting with blank model 'en'
Counting training words (limit=0)
C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\language.py:639: UserWarning: [W022] Training a new part-of-speech tagger using a model with no lemmatization rules or data. This means that the trained model may not be able to lemmatize correctly. If this is intentional or the language you're using doesn't have lemmatization data, please ignore this warning. If this is surprising, make sure you have the spacy-lookups-data package installed.
  **kwargs
C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\language.py:639: UserWarning: [W033] Training a new part-of-speech tagger using a model with no lexeme normalization table. This may degrade the performance of the model to some degree. If this is intentional or the language you're using doesn't have a normalization table, please ignore this warning. If this is surprising, make sure you have the spacy-lookups-data package installed. The languages with lexeme normalization tables are currently: da, de, el, en, id, lb, pt, ru, sr, ta, th.
  **kwargs
C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\language.py:639: UserWarning: [W033] Training a new parser or NER using a model with no lexeme normalization table. This may degrade the performance of the model to some degree. If this is intentional or the language you're using doesn't have a normalization table, please ignore this warning. If this is surprising, make sure you have the spacy-lookups-data package installed. The languages with lexeme normalization tables are currently: da, de, el, en, id, lb, pt, ru, sr, ta, th.
  **kwargs

Itn  Tag Loss    Tag %    Dep Loss    UAS     LAS    NER Loss   NER P   NER R   NER F   Token %  CPU WPS
---  ---------  --------  ---------  ------  ------  ---------  ------  ------  ------  -------  -------

⚠ Aborting and saving the final best model. Encountered exception: not enough
values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

✔ Saved model to output directory
models\model-final

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 463, in train
    scorer = nlp_loaded.evaluate(dev_docs, verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 687, in evaluate
    docs, golds = zip(*docs_golds)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 570, in train
    exits=1,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\printer.py", line 91, in warn
    title, text, style=MESSAGES.WARN, show=show, spaced=spaced, exits=exits
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\printer.py", line 244, in _get_msg
    title, text, color=style, icon=style, show=show, spaced=spaced, exits=exits
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\printer.py", line 152, in text
    sys.exit(exits)
SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 33, in <module>
    plac.call(commands[command], sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 367, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 232, in consume
    return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 617, in train
    best_model_path = _collate_best_model(final_meta, output_path, best_pipes)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 670, in _collate_best_model
    bests[component] = _find_best(output_path, component)
  File "C:\Users\Elske nijhof\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 689, in _find_best
    accs = srsly.read_json(epoch_model / "accuracy.json")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\srsly\_json_api.py", line 50, in read_json
    file_path = force_path(location)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\srsly\util.py", line 21, in force_path
    raise ValueError("Can't read file: {}".format(location))
ValueError: Can't read file: models\model0\accuracy.json
```

Comment: have you checked whether the file `models\model0\accuracy.json` exists?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes ofcourse! Just posted it :)

Comment: Yes I did, `models\modell0\accuracy.json` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicitly adding `-t json` but this seems to be a recent bug (2020-11-02) so you might have to upgrade spaCy.

[Source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4575)